# parse custom time in java 8

Tags: java, time, java-time

I want to create a one utility method that parses custom time strings like: `14h` , `17h30`.

I tried to use `LocalTime.ofPattern()` method using various pattern combination but I keep getting a `DateTimeParseException`

Edit:
I tried the following:
This throws an exception when the time is `14h`

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("14h", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("k'h'm"));
```

And this also throws an exception for `14h30`

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("9h30", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("k'h'"));
```

I learned from the comment that I can use the catch block to handle all the patterns but I wonder if there is a java time API that can accept a list of patterns

Comment: Can you show us any of your attempts with these *various pattern combination*s?

Comment: If you could show us one of those attempts we might actually have a chance of telling you what your mistake is.

Comment: You should have enough experience to understand that we can't help with such a request. Time to revisit [mcve]? And note: when your code has to deal with multiple different patterns, then OF COURSE you will run into such exceptions. Because the solution boils down to: you have a list of format patterns, and then your code tries one pattern after the other. If the pattern fits: no exception, otherwise you get an exception and try the next pattern.

Comment: `LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("14h", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H'h'[mm]"));`. Also works for `9h30` and `17h30`. The square brackets enclose an optional part of the format pattern string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would utilize a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` here in order to create a flexible `DateTimeFormatter` that parses a wide variety of input.

Create a `List<String>` of some possible test values, then loop through them and try to parse each one with that formatter.

Here's an example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // prepare some test values (don't know if all of them actually apply to your problem)
    List<String> times = List.of("17h", "17h30", "4h", "4h59", "09h", "09h21");
    // prepare a DateTimeFormatter with optional minutes of hour and a fixed 'h'
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .appendPattern("H")
                                    .appendLiteral('h')
                                    .optionalStart()
                                    .appendPattern("m")
                                    .optionalEnd()
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    times.forEach(time -> {
        try {
            // then try to parse each test value
            LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(time, dtf);
            // and print it if no exception was thrown
            System.out.println(localTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpEx) {
            // in case of an exception, print the value that could not be parsed
            String msg = String.format("Could not parse %s", time);
            System.err.println(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Output:

```
17:00:00
17:30:00
04:00:00
04:59:00
09:00:00
09:21:00
```

**Please note**: I used the symbol `H` for hour of day, but if your possible values really use `k` for clock-hour of day, then simply replace the `H` for `k`. The edge cases would be `00h` and `24h`. Consider involving them in your test cases ;-)

More information about the symbols can be found in
[the JavaDocs of `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Wouldn’t `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("k'h'[m]")` accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it would ;-) Definitely shorter, I just wanted to introduce the power of a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`…